# sidebar toggle background opacity not close

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a sidebar toggle and also gave background opacity but when I click another area or when closed the sidebar the background opacity didn't close. when I click the button the dropdown-content show and the background-opacity show but when I click again on the button the dropdown content closed but the background opacity does not close. How I did it. Please help me.  I gave the code below. If someone can help me it will be very helpful for me. I try so many times but in the end, I can't do it.

```js
 function toggleDropDown(id) {
        document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-content').forEach(el => el.id === id ? el.classList.toggle('show') : el.classList.remove("show"));
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
    }

    document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        // cases where we want to close the dropdown
        if (e.target.closest(".dropdown") === null) {
          document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-content').forEach(el => el.classList.remove("show"));
        }
      
    });
```

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
.dropdown-content{
  position: fixed;
  width: 30%;
  height:100%;
  background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
  margin-left: 20%;
  top:0;
  display:none;
  z-index:100;
}
.dropbtn{width:20%}
.show{display:block;}
```

```html
 <div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn" onclick="toggleDropDown('openContent')">open</button>
<div class="dropdown-content" id="openContent">Hello, Div</div>
</div>
<h1>Hello World, Heading 1</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would suggest to create a variable that keeps track of the current state of dropdown – which is either `true` or `false`.

Plus, I don’t see the benefit in using `document.querySelectorAll` and having to loop over every element, when you could just directly get the element by addressing its id (openContent)... unless you would want to reuse the function for other cases?

As you are also listening on a click event on the document, we have to watch out for event bubbling by calling `e.stopPropagation`. In the case of the `button` for example, this means that we only fire the event for the `button` but not for the `document`. Since the `button` is a child of the `document`, it would otherwise detect a click event for both and fire twice.

```js
const dropdownContent = document.getElementById("openContent");
let dropDownVisible = false;

function toggleDropDown(e) {
    // we need this to prevent the event bubbling from the dropdown button to the document
    e.stopPropagation();

    // set the dropDownVisible state to the opposite it has been before
    dropDownVisible = !dropDownVisible;

    if (dropDownVisible) {
        dropdownContent.classList.add("show");
        document.body.classList.add("bgcolor");
    } else {
        dropdownContent.classList.remove("show");
        document.body.classList.remove("bgcolor");
    }
}

// we need this to prevent the event bubbling from the dropdown to the document
dropdownContent.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
});

// listen for click events on the document
document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    // -> if the dropdown is visible, toggle its state
    dropDownVisible && toggleDropDown(e);
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.dropdown-content {
    position: fixed;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    margin-left: 20%;
    top: 0;
    display: none;
    z-index: 100;
}
.dropbtn {
    width: 20%;
}
.show {
    display: block;
}
.bgcolor {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn" onclick="toggleDropDown(event)">
                open
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content" id="openContent">Hello, Div</div>
  </div>
<h1>Hello World, Heading 1</h1>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to remove also the  "body" background.

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "initial";
```

```js
function toggleDropDown(id) {
        document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-content').forEach(el => el.id === id ? el.classList.toggle('show') : el.classList.remove("show"));
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
    }

    document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        // cases where we want to close the dropdown
        if (e.target.closest(".dropdown") === null) {
          document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-content').forEach(el => el.classList.remove("show"));
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "initial";
        }
      
    });
```

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
.dropdown-content{
  position: fixed;
  width: 30%;
  height:100%;
  background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
  margin-left: 20%;
  top:0;
  display:none;
  z-index:100;
}
.dropbtn{width:20%}
.show{display:block;}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
   <button class="dropbtn" onclick="toggleDropDown('openContent')">open</button>
   <div class="dropdown-content" id="openContent">Hello, Div</div>
</div>
<h1>Hello World, Heading 1</h1>
```

Comment: Thank u so much but one thing mistake to say that when I click the button the dropdown-content show and the opacity also show but when I click again on the button the dropdown content closed but the background opacity does not close. How I did it. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Add class  to body `document.body.classList.add('bgcolor');` and remove after close the dropdown

```js
function toggleDropDown(id) {
        document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-content').forEach(el => el.id === id ? el.classList.toggle('show') : el.classList.remove("show"));
      document.body.classList.add('bgcolor');
    }

    document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        // cases where we want to close the dropdown
        if (e.target.closest(".dropdown") === null) {
          document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-content').forEach(el => el.classList.remove("show"));
          document.body.classList.remove('bgcolor');
        }
      
    });
```

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
.dropdown-content{
  position: fixed;
  width: 30%;
  height:100%;
  background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
  margin-left: 20%;
  top:0;
  display:none;
  z-index:100;
}
.dropbtn{width:20%}
.show{display:block;}
.bgcolor{
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
```

```html
 <div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn" onclick="toggleDropDown('openContent')">open</button>
<div class="dropdown-content" id="openContent">Hello, Div</div>
</div>
<h1>Hello World, Heading 1</h1>
```

Comment: Thank u so much but one thing mistake to say that when I click the button the dropdown-content show and the opacity also show but when I click again on the button the dropdown content closed but the background opacity does not close. How I did it. Please help me.

Comment: please chk my snnipet it is working as you want

Comment: Yaa,, It's working thank u so much for this snippet but another problem mistake to say that when I click the button the dropdown-content show and the opacity also show now but when I click again on the button the dropdown content closed but the background opacity does not close.